# Reference a variable inside expression in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am displaying a form with Symfony2 and Twig, and need to display some fields in a dynamic order using a loop over an array. The code looks like this:

```
{% for activity in activities %}
  <div class="check">
    {{ form_label(tags_form.chactivity{{ activity.id }}) }}
    {{ form_widget(tags_form.chactivity{{ activity.id }}) }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But of course the `{{ activity.id }}` does not fit here.

How can I use the `activity.id` (integer) inside the `{{ form_label(...) }}` and `{{ form_widget(...) }}` expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function:

```
{{ form_label(attribute(tags_form, 'chactivity' ~ activity.id)) }}
```

Comment: I'm using 1.0, is there any way to do this in this version of Twig?

Comment: It was added in Twig 1.2. I suggest you to upgrade. Buy you could try this: `form_label(tags_form['chactivity' ~ activity.id])`.

Comment: Yes! Your comments works in 1.0. This will do while we update. Thanks.